# UnboundLocalError at / local variable 'user' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

I'm using django-favorite,https://bitbucket.org/last_partizan/django-favorites and trying to display "Get only blogpost favorites for user" strategy to get my favorites. in documentation, it says

```
content_type = get_object_or_404(ContentType, app_label='myblogapp', model='blogpost')
favs = Favorite.objects.favorites_for_user(user).filter(content_type=content_type)
```

will do the job. So in my views.py I have added

```
def index(request):
        user = MyProfile.objects.get(username=user)

        categories = Category.objects.all()
        try:
                sort = request.GET["sort"].strip()
                sort_method = SortMethods[sort]
                page = request.GET["page"].strip()
        except KeyError:
                sort_method = SortMethods.score
                page = 1

        if sort_method == SortMethods.date:
                post_list = Post.objects.order_by("-pub_date")
        else:
                post_list = Post.objects.all()
                post_list = sorted(post_list, key=lambda x: x.get_score(), reverse=True)

        paginator = Paginator(post_list, 30)

        try:
                posts = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
                posts = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
                posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        content_type = get_object_or_404(ContentType, app_label='main', model='post')
        favs = Favorite.objects.favorites_for_user(user).filter(content_type=content_type)
        context = {
                "posts": posts,
                "pages": paginator.page_range,
                "sort": sort_method.name,
                "categories":categories,
                "favs":favs,

        }
        return render(request, "main/index.html", context)
```

and to use that fav in my index.html, I have simply put {{fav}}, I'm not even sure this is the right way to call the favorites. But I tried and now it gives me UnboundLocalError at /

local variable 'user' referenced before assignment that's coming from `                 user = MyProfile.objects.get(username=user)

` I have userena app, inside userena model

```
  class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='my_profile')
    intro = models.CharField(_('intro'),
                                       max_length=5, default="Hello")
```

I'm calling from here to get user...I hope this is right.

Answer (score 0):

Should that first line be using:

```
request.user
```

So like this:

```
user = MyProfile.objects.get(username=request.user)
```

Comment: I tried bunch of things but with your solution I get Cannot query "Profile of nick": Must be "User" instance.

Comment: how do I assess user from userena? do you know? I have the model for userena above,,,i think this should be simpler than I think